# Joining on multiple conditions with multiple case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a join:

```
SELECT COLUMNA,COLUMNB..
FROM MYTABLE
JOIN ON
A1.B = B1.B
AND A1.C = B1.C
AND [JOIN ON SOME_CLAUSE1 AND SOME_CLAUSE2 ONLY IF CERTAIN CONDITIONS ARE MET]
```

Another words, if those "certain conditions" are not met, I only want to join on:

```
A1.B = B1.B
AND A1.C = B1.C
```

How would I do this?

Here's my non-pseudo code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   my TABLE 
JOIN 
on     Onyx.iownerid = mscrm.fi_id.search 
AND    onyx.question = mscrm.question 
AND    onyx.response = 
       CASE 
              WHEN onyx.questiontype IN (1,2) THEN 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN onyx.questiontype=2 THEN mscrm.answer 
                            WHEN onyx.questiontype=1 THEN 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT TOP 1 
                                                 vchparameterdesc 
                                          FROM   db..referenceparameters 
                                          WHERE  iparameterid=mscrm.answer) 
                     END 
       END
```

Comment: Can you provide us the structure of your tables and the conditions you want to apply? The expected result and a sample of data?

Comment: You can usually achieve this with some combination of AND, OR, and ().  But it depends on your exact "certain conditions".

Comment: Yes, I'm working on getting that for you. the last condition on which i am joining is a CASE STATEMENT

Comment: Can you further edit so that we can see which table is "Onyx" and which is "mscrm"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a pseudo answer for a pseudo question:

```
SELECT COLUMNA,COLUMNB..
FROM MYTABLE
JOIN ON
A1.B = B1.B
AND A1.C = B1.C
AND (
  CertainConditions = 'false'
  OR (SOME_CLAUSE1 AND SOME_CLAUSE2)
)
```

(post OP update, starting with the ON clause):

```
on     Onyx.iownerid = mscrm.fi_id.search 
AND    onyx.question = mscrm.question 
AND    (
   onyx.questiontype  NOT IN (1,2)
   OR (
      (onyx.questiontype=2 AND onyx.response = mscrm.answer)
      OR (onyx.questiontype=1 AND onyx.response=( 
                                          SELECT TOP 1 
                                                 vchparameterdesc 
                                          FROM   db..referenceparameters 
                                          WHERE  iparameterid=mscrm.answer
                                        ) 
          )
      )
   )
```

Oh and by the way, the above code assumes that none of the columns can be NULL.  If they can, you'll need to handle the possibilities of NULLs as well.

Comment: if this returns false: AND (
  CertainConditions = 'true'
  AND SOME_CLAUSE1 AND SOME_CLAUSE2 
)   then i dont want it at all included in the joining conditions

Comment: Did you mean to use OR instead?  Your answer means the same whether or not the parentheses are there, which violates the stipulation in the question about if CertainConditions is false that it only joins on the B and C columns.

Comment: oops, yes, I meant false + "or".  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman i've added a helpful edit, thank you for your time

Comment: Remember that NULL does not equal NULL, so you must use ISNULL() functions when comparing two values that might be NULL.